# Splitting a vector into several vectors when there is a change at a certain digit

Tags: matlab

```
    Let we have vector in Matlab such as

V = 
   0.000178395155017
   0.000213248167386
   0.000453830296775
   *0.000954267024225
   0.001985203786879
   0.002752603423106
   0.004236131760631
   0.005323800592906
   0.004742807895286
   0.005770068613768
   0.006502644472601
   0.007193873735489
   0.006799579314313
   0.007976014911026
   0.007799267839386
   0.008907651205854
   0.009190413742866
   0.008776108424259
   0.008578897868764
   0.009250162682559
   0.008646692914164
   0.008053809730819
   0.007451047998031
   0.006729120942615
   0.005979207722644
   0.007134289275269
   0.005186062958380
   0.005902382106719
   0.007762189959679
   0.008579238141806
   0.009485819832702
   0.009780236553648
   0.010538511758940
   0.012865379338644
   0.011390556215603
   0.010804154725939
   0.010290545066940
   0.009868360169125
   0.009357083973682
   0.008724843328595
   0.008560695909341
   0.008784388594649
   0.008739349797176
   0.008670604330509
   0.008753566233007
   0.008490628616888
   0.008003101497979
   0.008389140601319
   0.007282172470936
   0.006743970005005
   0.006452902620905
   0.005895958422668
   0.006326020573140
   0.005740103704853
   0.005142834616900
   0.004407465481546
   0.003835738957490
   0.004510955842245
   0.003693705366274
   0.002915993815608
   0.002889010498571
   0.003093844935832
   0.004282403818479
   0.003970929347537
   0.002819774971736
   0.003095369398698
   0.002920594268954
   0.002431265415582
   0.001949299679935
   0.001496954638334
   0.001096892239592
   0.001092281820070
   0.000790749599802
   0.000893827364410
   0.001334675844874
   0.001196368539888
   0.001160349994386
   0.001020290171146
   0.001112407234178
   0.001747377249787
   0.002765678114897
   0.003478849585666
   0.005355127628032
   0.004986389269550
   0.005947847852449
   0.006157789251547
   0.006181425650566
   0.006194151127049
   0.006269927746287
   0.006769754494212
   0.007712318414790
   0.008651586166082
   0.008790606282214
   0.009736113450469
   0.011185160343747
   0.012691072774672
   0.010504478607987
   0.014389683527318
   0.014831212205190
   0.028483974800043
   0.011080767592010
   0.011092374038746
   0.012487511417703
   0.013592769613900
   0.023109284793639
   0.011965905202027
   0.012215762791363
   0.013202467569807
   0.011692397524803
   0.011053425496442
   0.010772141978943
   0.010246937424879
   0.0099733483767118
   0.009945578183562
   0.010512885752603
   0.009531902580105
   0.008066298613627
   0.007407338182258
   0.007934227536212
   0.008839106853309
   0.007141630457420
   0.005890234651479
   0.005777682702918
   0.005975075824875
   0.007650395349746
   0.007857392419299
   0.005786229253901
   0.005200025773704
   0.004125852007666
   0.004066689824078
   0.003581520984740
   0.001457233291953
   0.001322814038819
   0.001253430603776
   0.002493349764335
   0.001702719375177
   0.001556075727362
   0.001200788268232
   0.000940090552841
   0.002078710051336
   0.001014764365464
   0.000954943700664
   0.001276066704394
   0.001359265944949
   0.001204978086943
   0.001593370287575
   0.001547390763560
   0.000930577956978
   0.000916566445246
   0.000546925307518
   0.013565059409590
   0.001282356857566
   0.015602976997836
   0.001499511920717
   0.001586946634746
   0.014156830819098
   0.000291360243454
   0.000429438521866
   0.000462155358170
   0.000362561191605
   0.000657801010925
   0.000593844882183
   0.000609582362382
   0.000310044384822
   0.000342618178403
   0.000282871074224
   0.000314326548349
   0.000204414827855
   0.000337206866696
   0.000532099888764
   0.001193470342198
   0.001296110099774
   0.000872141517716
   0.000700042872179
   0.000881365833141
   0.000373364170668
   0.000425611062469
   0.001421790419507
   0.000852308546181
   0.000815064422325
   0.000504599352342
   0.000700524140014
   0.000870732973155
   0.000714061606598
   0.001035552251181
   0.001149954823243
   0.001055911091689
   0.001199405112898
   0.001783769543970
   0.002409901173348
   0.003498367375372
   0.003703495953811
   0.006277776686302
   0.011652755634052
   0.010083799009042
   0.040863796019376
   0.013614001128299
   0.011042432683334
   0.015305185452370
   0.012711371813255
   0.016268067330822
   0.017370177368730
   0.019331483583318
   0.014673338103928
   0.017693568446981
   0.016892965150834
   0.014088831405978
   0.017200144763667
   0.014169123504048
   0.010078177083794
   0.014268458659556
   0.011690206086017
   0.006562739851251
   0.016466509298505
   0.015914670918691
   0.005624098695020
   0.017555623339083
   0.013692853335518
   0.004491863547507
   0.015326207984803
   0.014740709288865
   0.003199262301369
   0.013665227028721
   0.052745092682123
   0.029889776608225
   0.008659506247240
   0.008589034126194
   0.007785146195475
   0.007151058968527
   0.006980966929187
   0.005799220068642
   0.005386071463278
   0.004896307509138
   0.004818382921265
   0.004623210359464
   0.004383594039787
   0.003923666862792
   0.003524680860004
   0.003014782806900
   0.002558267907671
   0.002794987126812
   0.003018175443714
   0.003166769934104
   0.004138527203301
   0.004310037290568
   0.004610838173675
   0.004947713276471
   0.005083932336596
   0.005236700123762
   0.004687780786133
   0.004564827415894
   0.004302650724049
   0.004270824001320
   0.003937584195932
   0.003911947276786
   0.003620705359817
   0.003151576407325
   0.002751470077629
   0.002669908472863
   0.002232914262935
   0.002069299781104
   0.001979860796735
   0.001601476811607
   0.000301142580668
   0.000321068102647
   0.000390207925071
   0.000210753154473
   0.000387358708178
   0.000241971967384
   0.000366525972307
   0.000619750196280
   0.000412347959310
   0.000544608934404
   0.001311532428278
   0.000736536458620
   0.000523889409829
   0.000492076015774
   0.000297176544828
   0.000195452121510
   0.000292051729488
   0.000759425298714
   0.004267105657429
   0.000192598592911
   0.000235881092079
   0.000209623369819
   0.000160795350619
   0.000118611207140
   0.000253937140734
   0.000229140021426
   0.000132672582131
   0.000185947357453
   0.000336849580242
   0.000161741284909
   0.000212296295172
   0.000129317114703
   0.000078122221464
   0.000139606283922
   0.000074030291037
   0.000273018975900
   0.000084307182558
```

Our aim is to split it into some other vectors.
Th criteria to splitting is if:

1- There is a change in element `V(i)` and `V(i+1)`of at least 10e-1.

It store the indices into a new vector `W` and if:

2- their differences in indices is larger than 30, i.e., `W(j) - W(j+1) > 30`.

If these both conditions are satisfied then the vector would be split till the index `i`. otherwise would be left.
For example in the given vector, the output indices should be as:

```
 [4, 75, 185]
```

where the there would be 4 vectors:

```
V1 = [1:4]
V2 = [4:75]
v3 = [75:185]
V4 = [185:300]
```

What would you think about choosing a tolerance or having a criteria? 
Any idea is really appreciated.

Comment: please post the desired output for your input.

Comment: please edit you question accordingly, do not post it in the comments - it gets messy otherwise ;) And the question is, you don't know how many new vectors you will get, so wouldn't it be better to store the results in a cell array `output = { [0.0003,0.0008,0.0019,0.0027,0.0034] ; ... ; ...}`

Comment: @thewaywewalk Your suggestion for cell array is nice, by the way.

Comment: Are you saying you want the difference to vary? So that the difference between entry 5 and entry 6 should be 10e-1 and 19 entry 20 = 10e-2? You also don't mention whether the difference should be exact or >= or <=.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is:

```
V = [0.0003,0.0008,0.0019,0.0027,0.0034,0.0103,0.0110,0.0106,0.0113,0.0134,0.0143,0.0148,0.0152,0.0156,0.00166,0.00172,0.0174,0.0195,0.0193,0.000195,0.00021]

digit = 2;

output = accumarray(cumsum(logical([0; diff(floor(10^digit*V(:)))]))+1,V,[],@(x) {x})
```

gives you an cell array.

```
output = 

    [5x1 double]
    [9x1 double]
    [2x1 double]
    [3x1 double]
    [2x1 double]
```

[image]

some explainations:

```
%// get the important digit 
digs = floor(10^digit*V(:));
%// see where it changes
d = [0; diff(digs)];
%// convert to 0s and 1s and cumsum them up
subs = cumsum(logical(d))+1;
%// to get the subs for accumarray
output = accumarray(subs,V,[],@(x) {x})
```

Comment: What is the advantage of transposing `V` as in `V = V.'`?

Comment: @kkuilla you need a columnvector for accumarray. But I made a slightly change to avoid this line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a keen answer.

Comment: you're welcome. You should make your question a little clearer, there was a lot guessing on my side.

Comment: Why do you have to convert it to a logical? `cumsum([0; diff(floor(10^digit*V(:)))])` is not the same as `cumsum(logical([0; diff(floor(10^digit*V(:)))]))`. Both should be summed up imho but the first one is not. Only the one with `logical`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk As I told, my vectors have many elements and I want to split them if those changes in indices is more than 20. 
I mean assume the changes in digits are between pair elements (5,6), (8,9), and (30,31). Then the code should split the whole vector into two vectors instead of three. Because difference between last indices that have changes, i.e., (9,30) is more than 20 while difference between elements (6,8) is less than 20 and then code should leave them unchanged. I hope it is clear a bit!

Comment: To be honest, the answer does what you asked for in your question although a lot of assumptions had to be made. Remember to define your question clearly next time so that you get what you expect. My suggestion is that you play around with what you received, try to modify it yourself. Ask another question if you are stuck.

Comment: @kkuilla `diff` also returns **-1** -> `logical` converts -1 to 1, thats what I want to achieve. Well there are still some problems with my code, but as long as the OP doesn't clarify everythign, I'm not that motivated to continue working on it ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk I have edited my question. I hope it is clear a bit.